# Function to multiply checkbox/textbox values not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code works (applying a 10 or 15% discount to both the running CPC and total cost textboxes depending on which checkbox is selected) on the running CPC textbox, but only works one way on the total cost textbox. Why is this happening?

When you click a checkbox, it adds it's value to the total CPC, and then when an agency discount is selected it's value should be multiplied by either 0.9 or 0.85.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[name="percentdiscount"]').on('change', function() {
    applyDiscount();
  });

  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    let sum = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum).data('total', sum);
    applyDiscount();
  });

  function applyDiscount() {
    var pc = parseFloat($('input[name="percentdiscount"]:checked').val());
    var cpc = parseFloat($('input[id="sum"]').val());
    var noc = parseFloat($('input[id="numberofclickstextbox"]').val());
    $('#sum').val(function() {
      return ($(this).data('total') * pc);
    });
    $('#totalcost').val(function() {
      return ((noc * cpc) * pc).toFixed(2);
    });
  }
});

function calculatetier() {
  var myBox5 = document.getElementById('numberofclickstextbox').value;
  var myBox6 = document.getElementById('sum').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('totalcost');
  var myResult = myBox5 * myBox6;
  result.value = myResult.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="runningtotal">
  Running CPC Total (in £): <input id="sum" name="totalCPC" type="text" readonly="true" value="0.00" data-total="0" /> Total Cost (in £): <input id="totalcost" type="text" readonly="true" value="0 (until clicks specified)" data-total="0" />
</div>

<div class="campaignstrategy flex-child">
  <h1>1. Campaign Strategy</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="awareness" id="awareness_checkbox" value="0.01">Awareness<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="directresponse" id="directresponse_checkbox" value="0.01">Direct Response<br>
</div>

<div class="selecttier">
  <h1>5. Number of Clicks</h1>
  <input id="numberofclickstextbox" name="numberofclicks" type="text" value="0" data-total="0" oninput="calculatetier()" />
</div>

<div class="agencydiscount flex-child">
  <h1>6. Agency Discount</h1>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="" value="1" checked>
        None
      </label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="10percent" value="0.9">
        10%
      </label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="15percent" value="0.85">
        15%
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add all the relevant code to reproduce your issue, like `calculatetier()` function.

Comment: @Triby apologies I thought I'd included everything

Comment: Are you sure, it's all the code that we need, I paste in my local and iclude jquery but doesn't do anything. Please share your code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: @QuethzelDíaz, it's better to use a Code Snippet, so we can test here.

Comment: @Triby I have added another div of checkboxes and can confirm the snippet shows the issue I'm having

Comment: You're not providing a value for `data-total`; besides, I don't think it's a good idea to create a function for getting #sum and #totalcost values.